# Is it possible to import in forms.py values from a view function Django? Is there another way to create functions in forms.py?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

In my **forms.py** I have a section of code which gives me an error when I try to migrate for the first time. So I thought a good solution would be to change the location of the code.

This is the problem section:

```py
tags = Tag.objects.all()
choice_list_tags =[]
for tag in tags:
    choice_list_tags.append(tag)
```

Its role is to create a list which is used in widgets -> tags -> choices

And this is my **forms.py**:

```py
from django import forms

from .models import BlogPost, Category, Tag

class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    tags = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

tags = Tag.objects.all()
choice_list_tags =[]
for tag in tags:
    choice_list_tags.append(tag)

class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'preview_content', 'private', 'tags']


        widgets ={
                'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'preview_content': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'private': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-label'}),
                'tags': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=choice_list_tags, attrs={'class': 'form-check-label'}),
            }
```

I tried to create in **context_processors.py** a function and import the values in forms.py but I dont know how. Iam not sure that's the solution either

```py
def tag_list():
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    choice_list_tags =[]
    for tag in tags:
        choice_list_tags.append(tag)
    return {'choice_list_tags':choice_list_tags}
```

If there is any other solution to avoid the error for the first migration or to make the logic in a view and import it in **forms.py**? I am rly waiting for your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In my little experience, you import from forms.py into views.py

Hope this helps. If you find another solution point me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
def SimpleFormviews(request):
    form=forms.SimpleForm()
return(render,'aapname/name.html',{'form':forms})
```